# Segmentation fault when dereferencing pointer inside the destructor

Tags: c++, qt, destructor

I have a header file `part.h` as follows:

```
#ifndef _PART_H_
#define _PART_H_
#include <QPointer>
#include <QUrl>
class Sidebar;
class TOC;
namespace Okular
{
class OKULARPART_EXPORT Part : public KParts::ReadWritePart, public Okular::DocumentObserver, public KDocumentViewer, public Okular::ViewerInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Part(QWidget* parentWidget, QObject* parent, const QVariantList& args);

        // Destructor
        ~Part();

    public:
        bool closeUrl() override;
        bool closeUrl(bool promptToSave) override;

    private:
        Sidebar * m_sidebar;
        QPointer<TOC> m_toc;
};
}
#endif
```

And then the file `part.cpp` as:

```
#include "part.h"
namespace Okular
{

Part::Part(QWidget *parentWidget,
QObject *parent,
const QVariantList &args)
: KParts::ReadWritePart(parent),
m_tempfile( nullptr ), m_documentOpenWithPassword( false ), m_swapInsteadOfOpening( false ), m_isReloading( false ), m_fileWasRemoved( false ), m_showMenuBarAction( nullptr ), m_showFullScreenAction( nullptr ), m_actionsSearched( false ),
m_cliPresentation(false), m_cliPrint(false), m_cliPrintAndExit(false), m_embedMode(detectEmbedMode(parentWidget, parent, args)), m_generatorGuiClient(nullptr), m_keeper( nullptr )
{
  // constructor code here

m_sidebar = new Sidebar( parentWidget );
    setWidget( m_sidebar );
}

Part::closeUrl(bool promptToSave)
{
m_sidebar->setCollapsed(promptToSave);
}

Part::~Part()
{
m_sidebar->setCollapsed(true); //segmentation fault
delete m_toc;
}
}//namespace Okular
```

When dereferecing `m_sidebar` inside the destructor `Part::~Part`, I'm getting `segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. `m_sidebar` is a pointer variable of type `class Sidebar` which is implemented in `sidebar.cpp`.
Why I'm getting it as I think `m_sidebar` is not null as it was intialized in `Part::Part` constructor and it works in `Part::closeUrl()` function.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual, when you pass your widget to `setWidget`, you pass the ownership to another widget. You should not try to access `m_sidebar` in the destructor.

> The widget becomes a child of the scroll area, and will be destroyed when the scroll area is deleted or when a new widget is set.

You can subscribe for the signal `Sidebar::destroyed` and when this signal emitted reset `m_sidebar = nullptr`.

Comment: I didn't  deleted `m_sidebar` inside the destructor `Part::~Part`. Is there any other code/class deleting this before reacing to `Part` class destructor?

Comment: Do not cling to words. I think it is quite clear that `m_sidebar` is already deleted and can not be accessed.